# document.getElementById("<%= btnLogout.ClientID %>").click(); not working on some pages

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Even though it is working on the rest of the pages correctly, it is not on some pages.

This block of code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="logout" onclick="logouttest(); return false;" class="">
   Logout </a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function logouttest() {
    document.getElementById("<%= btnLogout.ClientID %>").click();
}
```

Comment: please check the error on console (press F12) where not working.

Comment: check the value of <%= btnLogout.ClientID %>. does these pages have btnLogout id?

Comment: Is the `JS` within a external javascript file?  If so, that's the issue, ASP.Net does not process .js files so you are literally sending ASP.Net based commands for the browser to deal with (hint, that doesn't work).  Move the function into the .aspx/ascx file that contains the control

Comment: @jitendra this code not showing any error...i checked it

Comment: @freefaller no its not externally added...it is on aspx only...does it is affecting because of some other code or else..?

Comment: @KarthikMR it is showing "btnLogout" as a id value. but still not working

Comment: so, <%= btnLogout.ClientID %> value is "btnLogout" ?

Comment: @KarthikMR   Yes...but still not working

Comment: can you check in your browser console by executing document.getElementById('btnLogout') and check if there is any error

Comment: @KarthikMR yes i checked it ...it is not showing any error but not working too.